# How to setup javascript redirect to send user to back page? see code

Tags: javascript, jquery

With `onclick="history.go(-1);return false;"` user can navigate to back pages. But if I want to put a confirm method before it takes user to the back. How would I do that?

I think it can be achieved by doing something like below but I am not sure how to redirect user to back page?

```
$('.clickme').click(function() {
    if(confirm("Are you sure you want to navigate away from this page?"))
    {
      //window.close();
      // how to redirect to history.go(-1) ??
    }        
    return false;
 });
```

**UPDATE**

Also is there any way I can check if history has some values in it or is empty? So that I can alert user if is empty?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

It's quite as simple as you think it is:

```
$('.clickme').click(function() {
   if(confirm("Are you sure you want to navigate away from this page?"))
   {
      history.go(-1);
   }        
   return false;
});
```

Comment: is there any way to check if there is "something" in history .. i.e. not empty etc??

Comment: There exist a history.previous property but as the JSRef states it *requires the UniversalBrowserRead privilege. It has no value if you do not have this privilege. For information on security, see the Client-Side JavaScript Guide.*

Comment: yes, you can check `history.length`. `onclick="if(history.length == 0) { alert("there's nowhere to go!"); } else { if(confirm('are you sure?')) { history.go(-1); } }"`

Answer (score 12):

Try this:

```
    if(confirm("Are you sure you want to navigate away from this page?"))
    {
      history.back();
    }
```

Comment: can it be put in onclick="return confirm('confirm message')";??

Answer (score 3):

```
$('.clickme').click(function() { 
        if(history.length != 0)
        {
            if(confirm("Are you sure you want to navigate away from this page?")) 
            { 
                history.go(-1);
            }
         return false;
        }
        alert("No history found");
        return false;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.clickme').click(function() { 
    if(history.length != 0)
        {
            if(confirm("Are you sure you want to navigate away from this page?")) 
            { 
                document.location.replace(document.referrer)
            }
        return false;
        }
        alert("No history found");
        return false;
});
```

(This code draws heavily on Dodswarm's answer.)

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"> 

function goBack() 
{
 window.history.back()
}

window.onkeyup = function (e) 
{
 if (e.keyCode == 27) window.history.back();
}
</script>
```

Add above code in your head section of page. Here whenever user press <kbd>Esc</kbd> button then he will be redirected to previous view page and if we want to add this logic on back button press then just call `goback()` on click event.